# One-Time-Password in C# expires after a certain period?

Tags: c#, asp.net, one-time-password

I'm working on a log in page for a website now in C#.net and have encountered an issue, and was hoping you guys could help me out.

This is the case :
The user comes over to the log in screen, then from there they key in their e-mail, we'll reference with the database to check for validity, and if it's valid, a random 8 digit key will be generated and sent to the email. The user should now check his/her email to get the "One-time-password" and then key into one text box to proceed.

The generation and email sending has been done, but I'm not sure how to continue doing this

There's some discussion among my team members, one of them proposed to use a session timeout, and then when the button is clicked, the email will be sent , a session variable will be created and have the one time password stored in it, then we will reference the textbox's text which the user has entered with the session variable and if it's correct, they'll be logged in.

Another way I was thinking of is to use Javascript timers, then reference with an invisible label on the web page. But I'm not sure if Javascript can allow that to happen..

What are your best approaches to this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Uhh, got to add in a comment here, I'm looking for a way to do this without interacting with the database as it's more complicated.. I was wondering if there's a way to do so without storing into the database ><

Answer (score 7):

It is time sensitive, just store the code in the database with an expiration datetime.  Then when the user comes back with their token you can see if it is has not yet expired, if it has then ask them to start the process over.

Comment: In principle on could also put the expiration time in the token in encrypted form. But that's pretty easy to get wrong.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, doing that would likely be fine in practice, but if an attacker figures out how these expiration times are encrypted, he/she could potentially create his/her own tokens with custom expiration times. On the contrary, assuming the database is protected from SQL injection, this attack is mitigated.

Comment: @SpencerDoak Personally I like storing the hash of the token in a database (so read access to the db isn't enough to learn the token) together with the expiration date. But producing a valid MAC on a forged token requires a leak of the key stored on the server, which shouldn't happen, just like an attacker shouldn't be able to access the database.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, ah, now that I can agree with. A signature of the one-time password would indeed be safer to store in the database along with the expiration time. I was merely remarking that entrusting the user with the expiration time (even if it was encrypted) might not be the safest idea. But again, I do believe you are right that storing a hash of the token in the database along with its expiration time would be wise.